# AngularJS + Laravel -- Eloquent retrieving username by user ID

Tags: json, angularjs, laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm building an application that has Angular on the front-end and Laravel on the back. My question is, how do I return/retrieve the user's fullname by using their "author_id" on the posts table against "user_id" on the users table? I have a users table and a posts table looking like this:

```
users table
user_id | fullname | email | password | active

posts table
post_id | author_id (FK-user_id on users table) | text | timestamps
```

My User Model looks like this:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post', 'author_id');
}
```

And my Post Model looks like this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'author_id');
}
```

Assuming my routing is correct (it is, I can provide it if need be), my PostController has this method for retrieving Posts:

```
public function getAllPostsByUserID($user_id)
{
    $posts = Post::where("user_id", "=", $user_id)
                            ->get();

    if($posts) {
        return Response::json($posts);
    } else {
        return Response::json(array('flash'=>'No posts by this user.'),500);
    }
}
```

Right now, I am retrieving a JSON that has all the user's posts, but because the posts table uses author_id, I can't display the user's name, only his ID. I've seen how this works on Laravel/Blade where you can chain methods and then access the user's fullname because of the Eloquent relationship of hasMany or belongsTo, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this while returning a JSON to the Angular side.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: actually no difference using blade or angular in logic,did you handle by the way?

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve all posts of a user, you could do the following:

```
$user = User::with('post')->whereUserId($user_id)->first();
```

This will give you the $user object and you will be able to access collection of user's post with

```
$posts = $user->post;
```

It's also not neccessary to do:

```
return Response::json($posts);
```

When you return a Collection or Eloquent object Laravel will serialize it to **JSON** automatically. If you switch to the code above to fetch user with their posts, it will be enough to just do:

```
return $user;
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to fetch a collection of posts with related users, you can do:

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->get();
```

You'll get a collection of **Post** objects and each of them will have a **user** attribute holding the related user.

Comment: Retrieving all the posts by a user isn't exactly what im looking for, i'm trying to return all the posts in the table and display them, but since I'm getting a JSON of the post, I'm unable to retrieve the user's name, only their ID, which is useless when displaying a post. Thanks for the pointer on the return Response::json(), didn't know that one!

Comment: Well, your method is called getAllPostsByUserID($user_id) so it's retrieving all posts for given user :) If you want to get all posts and the related users, have a look at the updated answer (in a moment)

Comment: Haha sorry! I totally forgot to include that into the question. Thanks very much!

Comment: Hmm interesting, I'll try this right now. This will return the related user, but how would I get their name from the users table. Also, can you briefly explain what the parameters for the with() method is? Thanks!

Comment: $post->user->name will give you the name of related user. with() takes as argument a list of relations that should be loaded with the model - see more info about eager loading here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: $post->user->name will work for blade, but how would I use that in Angular?

Comment: Sorry, forgot you need that for Angular :) Your API will return a list of objects representing posts. each of them will have a user attribute. So in order to access name of user that created the first post you do console.log(data[0].user.name);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84966/discussion-between-user3794832-and-jedrzej-kurylo).